# W3C validation error - stray tags

Tags: html, validation, tags, w3c-validation

This question has been asked before but the given answer does not apply here.
I am getting 2 errors, a stray end  tag and and error saying that the body already appears to be open (stray open body tag).

I have checked each page of my new WIP and I have put the doctype then the html, open head (content), close head (once) open body etc.

When i click on the tags in Dreamweaver they match up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Music Matters – Home</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/musicmatters.css" media="screen"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png"/><meta name="author" content="Rachel Gallen"/>
```

(unnecessary body removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a link in your head which is [invalid](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/head.html#head):

```
<a rel="author" class="author" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/116320582037506211575?rel=author">Rachel Gallen</a>
```

Remove it and the page validates.